# Maximum power across a transistor

Tags: led, power, transistors

How can I find out what is the maximum power through a transistor? Can I look at just the data sheet (if I do look at one, what am I looking for) or do I have to use a meter to figure out the max power through an LED/transistor or a switch. All the components are a part of a circuit, with a purpose of lighting up LED's.

Answer (score 4):

The power dissipated by a transistor in a circuit is determined by the usual power formula: P = E x I - that is, the power is the voltage across the transistor times the current through the transistor.

The maximum recommended power dissipation for a transistor will be found in the data sheet, under "Total Device Dissipation", or words to that effect.  There may also be a graph of power dissipation vs ambient temperature.

Answer (score 1):

> **How can I find out what is the maximum power through a transistor? Can I look at just the data sheet (if I do look at one, what am I looking for)**

In the [data sheet](http://www.ligo.caltech.edu/~citsas/HAM-SAS/Electronics/lvdtdrv1.0/datasheets/2N290X.pdf), you are looking for this

> ### ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS
>
> [image]

You'll also want to take into account this

[image]

Comment: I'm Sorry, I am new to this. How do I co-relate the power dissipation with the thermal data?

Comment: @ShP: Unless I am mistaken, the thermal resistance in this example tells you the junction temperature will be 292 + 21 = 313°C if the transistor is dissipating 1 Watt (Vce * Ic) at 21°C ambient - 313°C is much much more than enough to destroy a semiconductor junction. This transistor isn't designed to have a heat-sink attached so you must keep the power level far below this.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you'll find two parameters in the datasheet:

- Maximum Drain (or Collector) continuous current
- Maximum Drain-to-Source (or Collector-to-Emitter) voltage

The maximum continuously dissipated power is just a product of the two parameters above.

Notes:

Often, the maximum power dissipated by the transistor will be determined by its heat dissipation capability. In order to help the transistor to cool down you need to attach it to a heatsink. Heatsinks come in a variety of shapes and sizes, both of them affecting its heat dissipation. If you try to operate some transistor at continuous power which is higher than what can be safely dissipated by the transistor and the heatsink - the transistor will burn out.

Comment: Downvoting because wrong.  Consider an IRF510, with absmax Vds of 100V and absmax Id of 4A.  You are saying it should be able to dissipate 400 W continuously?  In reality absmax Pd is 43 W.

Comment: @markrages, if I understand the datasheet correctly, then it can deliver 400W continuously. It will burn out after some time, and this what I meant to warn OP about in the NOTE section. Yes, there are applications where this transistor can be operated at 400W with ~10% duty cycle. I don't understand why you are claiming my answer is wrong. Can you be more specific?

Comment: the power dissipated in a transistor is different than the power delivered to the load.  (the relationship between the two powers, called "efficiency", is related to circuit topology.

Comment: The absolute maximum power is rated at 43 W.  The transistor can't dissipate 400 W.  I'm not aware of any TO-220 device that can dissipate 400 W.  Are you talking about power delivered to a load?

Comment: Roughly speaking, current limits are about the width of the devce, and breakdown voltages are about the thickness of the device, and power limits are about the mounting of the device in its case and heatsink assembly.  These three things are not necessarily related.

Comment: @markrages, to my best knowledge the power is defined by \$P=IV\$, or \$P=I^2R_{ON}\$ which is the same. I agree that this power may differ from the equivalent power of heat, but I've never seen a question about MOSFET power dissipation which considers the latter as the definition of power. The question was about the maximum power through a transistor, and I provided the answer and warned the OP about overheating issue. This is the best i can do. Maybe I'm wrong though. My favorite reference for power FETs: https://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-558.pdf