# NPN Transistor- max power

Tags: transistors

I have studied the datasheet of an NPN transistor, in datasheet MAX-POWER OF transistor is mention as 400 mW.

What is the meaning of max power?

Can it be generated by itself or do I have to give 400 mW to the transistor??

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82981/maximum-power-across-a-transistor) can be helpful to you. There it is explained that the maximum power of a transistor is the total power that it can dissipate, so in your case, your NPN transistor is able to dissipate 400mW when it is activated.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Also check the temperature derating. Specified max dissipation is usually at 25C case or heatsink temperature.

Comment: Lead length affects the heat removal. Some people attach small heat sinks atop the transistor's case, and let airflow provide more cooling.